# Add Mx1 size data frame to MxN size data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add this data frame

Dataframe 1 (size 3X1):

```
>> df1
   0
0  2.0
1  1.0
2  3.0
```

To this data frame:

Dataframe 2 (size 3x3):

```
>> # actually number of columns > 3
>> df2
    0   1    2
0  100  200 300
1  110  210 310
2  120  220 320
```

Yielding:

```
   0   1    2
0  102  202 302
1  111  211 311
2  123  223 323
```

namely add `d1` to every column in `d2`, according to their corresponding row.
But why this won't do:

```
>> df1 + df2
        0   1    2
    0  102  NA NA
    1  111  NA NA
    2  123  NA NA
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Replicate the columns in your first dataframe and then add both dataframes would be one of the way to proceed.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.concat(3*[df1], axis=1, ignore_index=True) + df2
     0    1    2
0  102  202  302
1  111  211  311
2  123  223  323
```

I assumed there you know how many times you need to concatenate the columns (here 3) !

Answer (score 2):

Making no assumption about the indices and if they are aligned or not, you can align the rows first by using `.reindex_axis` and then use numpy broadcasting rules over `.values`, and finally re-construct the frame:

```
>>> df1.values + df2.reindex_axis(df1.index).values
array([[ 102.,  202.,  302.],
       [ 111.,  211.,  311.],
       [ 123.,  223.,  323.]])
>>> pd.DataFrame(_, columns=df2.columns, index=df2.index)
     0    1    2
0  102  202  302
1  111  211  311
2  123  223  323
```